# How to summit a post with line break in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

It seems like rails treat every post with line break by change the line break into a space.

for example:

when I type

```
        hi
        hi
        hi
```

in my form, what I get is just a simple "hi hi hi". How to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that in post form for `description` field you may have taken `textarea`

as Rustam commented you can use [simple_format](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format) helper method: Two or more consecutive newlines(\n\n) are considered as a paragraph and wrapped in `<p>` tags.

You can use like

```
<%= simple_format(@post.description) %>
```

I hope this work out for you..

Comment: There is a special helper in Rails for this, called [`simple_format`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format)

Comment: feed back: gsub way dosent work, it will show </br> on content. simple_format way works fine :D

Comment: @HaisongHuang : Thanks for your feedback. I haven't use that now I have removed another option so in future no one mislead.